# ACID transactions across multiple technologies

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I have an application that uses a local database and a remote database to synchronize to. The local database uses SQLite and for the remote database I'm using postgres. I need to move data from one database to the other database and avoid duplicating information.

Roughly what I do right now:

```
BEGIN;                                       //remote database  (start transaction)
SELECT * FROM local.queued TOP 1;            //local database   (select first queued element)
INSERT INTO remote.queued VALUES ( element ) //remote database  (insert first queued element on remote database)
BEGIN;                                       //local database   (start transaction)
DELETE * FROM local.queued LIMIT 1;          //local database   (delete first queued element on local database)
END;                                         //local database   (finalize transaction local database)
END;                                         //remote database  (finalize transaction remote database)
```

This works relatively well most of the times but incidentally, after giving a hard reset to the program I've noticed a data record was duplicated. I believe this is has something to do with the transaction finalizing. Because I'm using two distinct technologies it would be impossible to create a single atomic commit with WAL archiving.

Any ideas how I could improve this concept to avoid duplicative entries.

Comment: Have you come across the saga pattern?

Comment: PostgreSQL has XA drivers, but as far as I know SQLite doesn't. Two-phase-commit isn't probably an option here.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do that is a *distributed transaction* using the *two-phase commit protocol*.

Unfortunately SQLite doesn't seem to support it, but since PostgreSQL does, you can still use it if only two databases are involved:

```
BEGIN;  -- on PostgreSQL

              BEGIN;  -- on SQLite

   /*
    * Do work on both databases.
    * On error, ROLLBACK both transactions.
    */

PREPARE TRANSACTION 'somename';  -- PostgreSQL

              COMMIT;  -- SQLite

COMMIT PREPARED 'somename';  -- PostgreSQL
```

Now if an error happens during the SQLite `COMMIT`, you run `ROLLBACK PREPARED 'sonename'` on PostgreSQL. The idea is that everything that can fail during commit is done during `PREPARE TRANSACTION`, and the state of the transaction is persisted so that it stays open, but will still survive a server restart.

This is safe, but there is a caveat. Prepared transactions are dangerous, because they will hold locks and keep `VACUUM` from cleaning up (like all other transactions), but they are persistent and stick around until you explicitly remove them. So you need some piece of software, a *distributed transaction manager*, that is crash safe and keeps track of all distributed transactions. This transaction manager can clean up all prepared transactions after some outage.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make sense to make your DML actions *idempotent* - that is to say that if you call them multiple times they have the same overall effect. For example, we can make the INSERT a no-op if the data exists:

```
INSERT INTO x(id, name)
SELECT nu.id, nu.name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 as id, 'a' as name) as nu
  LEFT JOIN x ON nu.id = x.id
WHERE
  x.id IS NULL
```

You can run this as many times as you like, and it'll only insert one record

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nbHmy3PVDQ3RrGMqLni1su/0

YOu'll need to decide what to do if the record exists in an altered state - eg do you want to leave it alone, or reset it to the incoming values - a question for another time